# on click div showing but not hide please help me

Tags: jquery

when i click on Number One link and product detail is now shown but when i click again then product detail div is not going to hide please see link:

Here's [a link](http://www.scriptscale.com/blog/portfolio_html/Example%20WEb/atuacao.html)

Comment: You're going to need to provide your code. Please don't expect the community to visit an unknown site and sift through your script.

Comment: Please post your code here so that people can follow along should the link become inactive.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hassanjaved/hLd5W/3/ please see this link

Comment: @Hassan, please post the relevant parts of your code *in your question itself*. External links can (and will) rot and die someday, and then your question will be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see your updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/hLd5W/4/

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    var previs = $('div.product-detail:visible');
    $('div.product-detail').hide();
    if (previs.is($('.det' + id))) {
        $('.det' + id).hide()
    }
    else
    {
        $('.det' + id).show();
    }

    //if (detailedDiv.is(':visible')) detailedDiv.hide();
    //else detailedDiv.show();
    e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Oh Thanks brother :* thanks very Much all worked :)

Comment: after prod9  and det9 its not working.!!  :( please help me :( when i edit prod10 its goes to det1 :( help me pleaseeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

Please see this solution. is it fine?

http://jsfiddle.net/hLd5W/10/

```
var last_clicked_id = 0;
$(function(){   

jQuery('a[id^="prod"]').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    $(".product-detail").hide();

    if(last_clicked_id != id){
        $('.det'+id).show();
    }
    last_clicked_id = id; 


});
});
```

Comment: its not working brother i try that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hassanjaved/hLd5W/3/

please see this link

Comment: I have updated the answer above in jsfiddle. please check it.

Comment: when click again and then its not open, and after prod9  and det9 its not working.!!

Answer (score 0):

change your click event to this:

```
$(function(){   
  $('a[id^="prod"]').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);

    // Hide all .product-detail divs except the one you want to toggle.
    $('div.product-detail:not(.det' + id + ')').hide();

    // Toggle show/hide the desired div
    $('div.product-detail.det'+id).toggle();

    return false;
  });
});
```

Btw, it is still ass-ugly, I just modified your code to make it work. I would add attributes like data-id="N" on the elements so I don't have to use slice() and concatenate strings.

Also, like others pointed out, put your code and html in the question, don't expect us to follow your link.